# Split long strings every 255 characters

Tags: c#, oledb

I want to split the `qc` column every 255 characters into multiple strings and then concat them back together when I Insert them into Excel. I've tried about everything I can think of, I know this is dumb, but I thought I would ask, but how would I go about doing this? This is my insert code. Thanks!

```
string lFilename = "myExcel.xls";
string lDistributorFolder = Server.MapPath(".") + "\\Portals\\0\\Distributors\\" + _currentUser.UserID.ToString() + "\\";
string lTemplateFolder = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CPCeCommerceTemplates"];
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(lDistributorFolder);

File.Copy(lTemplateFolder + lFilename, lDistributorFolder + lFilename, true);
string lConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + lDistributorFolder + "\\" + lFilename + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;\"";
DbProviderFactory lFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");
int lSequence = 0;
using (DbConnection lConnection = lFactory.CreateConnection())
{
    lConnection.ConnectionString = lConnectionString;
    lConnection.Open();

    foreach (DataRowView rowView in dv)
    {
        DataRow row = rowView.Row;

        lSequence++;

        using (DbCommand lCommand = lConnection.CreateCommand())
        {

            lCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Sheet1$]";
            lCommand.CommandText += "([First Name],[Last Name],[Title],[Company],[Address],[Address 2],[City],[State],[Zip],[Country],[Work phone],[Email],[Website],[Stamp Time],[Campaign],[Source],[Business Unit],[Market Segment],[Notes],[Other Source Detail],[Description],[Sales Employee firstname],[Sales Employee last name],[Reason],[Status],[Category],[Priority]) ";
            lCommand.CommandText += "VALUES(";
            lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["name"].ToString().Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
            lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["lastname"].ToString().Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
            lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["title"].ToString().Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
            lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["company"].ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"").Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
            lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["address"].ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"").Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
            lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["address2"].ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"").Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
            lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["city"].ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"").Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
            lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["state"].ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"").Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
            lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["zip"].ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"").Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
            lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["country"].ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"").Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
            lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["workphone"].ToString() + "\",";
            lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["email"].ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"").Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
            lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["website"].ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"").Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
            lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["stamptime"].ToString() + "\",";
            lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["campaign"].ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"").Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
            lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["source"].ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"").Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
            lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + string.Empty + "\",";
            lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["market"].ToString() + "\",";
            lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["qc"].ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"").Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
            lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["othersourcedetail"].ToString() + "\",";
            lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + string.Empty + "\",";
            lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + string.Empty + "\",";
            lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + string.Empty + "\",";
            lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + "Lead" + "\",";
            lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + "Open" + "\",";
            lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + "Lead" + "\",";
            lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + "High" + "\"";
            lCommand.CommandText += ")";
            lCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    lConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Just an unrelated suggestion but you might want to use a StringBuilder to build the CommandText since you do A LOT of string concatenation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx

Comment: @DJKRAZE I don't believe there is operator overloading involved here?

Comment: Does the original data that you were trying to return and insert into excel have comma delims..? if so what not read the data from the query into a List<T> then based on each line do a Split.. you could even load this into a Dictionary.. and create your own comma delim file that you can actually import or insert into Excel..

Comment: MCKay I mean to say compound operator my bad.. either way it's ugly technique in my opinion he's using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This LINQ is not pretty, but it will split any string, `str`, that you specify into a number of parts, each of length `len` (and, in the case of the last part, less).

```
int len = 4;
string str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

string[] parts =
    str.Select((chr, index) => new { chr, index })
       .GroupBy(entry => entry.index / len)
       .Select(group => new string(group.Select(entry => entry.chr).ToArray()))
       .ToArray();
```

This may be slightly more legible:

```
string[] parts =
    Enumerable.Range(0, (str.Length - 1) / len + 1)
              .Select(i => str.Substring(i * len, Math.Min(len, str.Length - i * len)))
              .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

String.Substring(0, 255). Do a loop and position. split the sentence. save it to an array and keep looping every 255 characters until the string position reaches the string end.

Loop. split every 255. remember the position in the string.

Answer (score 0):

This linq is not that pretty, but I still like it...

```
int len = 255;
for (int i = 0; i < big.Length; i += len )
{
    string clip = new string(big.Skip(i).Take(len).ToArray());
}
```